# Disable the entire form at once (Angular reactive form)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder

Is there any way to disable the entire form in angular when using Reactive forms. I know it is possible to make them disable one by one.

```
 this.tempForm = this.fb.group({
  m26_type:  '',
  m26_name:  ''
 })
this.tempForm.get('m26_type').disable();
```

Is it possible to disable the whole form rather than make every controller disable separately?

Comment: Have a look at [AbstractControl.disable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
this.tempForm.disable();
```

> Disables the control. This means the control will be exempt from
>   validation checks and excluded from the aggregate value of any parent.
>   Its status is DISABLED.
>
> If the control has children, all children will be disabled to maintain
>   the model.

[LINK](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable)

**UPDATE**

Plunker link - https://plnkr.co/edit/CFC4uKpvfE4otJ2PWdkc?p=preview

Comment: @Freak001 updated the code with a plunker link check that

Comment: @Freak001 jope it helped ?

Comment: Yeah it helped. In my case problem was I am using custom form controls in reactive forms. When using custom form controls i reactive forms need to implement setDisabledState(). https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: Remember for template driven forms the code is ngFormName.form.disable() or enable(). Also they are functions as the properties 'disabled' and 'enabled' are read-only.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the template driven (with ngModel) you can add to your code also

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
//at ts
//create view child
@viewChild('myForm')form:any;
//and in your function of reset
this.form.disable()
```