# Angular Reactive Form: ReadOnly - Difference between fieldset disabled and formgroup.disable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to make a Angular Reactive Form ReadOnly, so it cannot be edited.
Currently seeing two methods below. What is the difference between the two strategies mentioned?

**Option 1:**

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <fieldset [disabled]="true">
        ...
    </fieldset>
```

**Option 2**

```
this.testform.disable();
```

**Resource:**

[Disable the entire form at once (Angular reactive form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854017/disable-the-entire-form-at-once-angular-reactive-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively no difference.

The first one can be used in template driven forms as well while later is obviously part of reactive forms.