# How to disable all field in a div/form in Angular 16?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have tried to disable all html elements in a form in Angular 16.
But it is not working as expected.
But in the Google Login Form all fields including `<a>` tag are in disabled state.

[image]

This my login.component.html

```
<div class="signin-wrapper">
  <mat-card>
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Sign in</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input required matInput type="email" placeholder="eg. test@email.com" formControlName="userEmailAddress">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input required matInput type="password" placeholder="eg. ************" formControlName="userPassword">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
      <mat-card-footer>
        <div class="text-center">Not Registered? <a routerLink="../register">Register</a></div>
      </mat-card-footer>
    </form>
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="inProgress" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

I am using

> this.loginForm.disable()

to disable the form. The result is

[image]

In the above form `<a>` tag and `<button>` are not disabled.

Then I tried with `<fieldset [disabled]="true">`

```
<div class="signin-wrapper">
  <mat-card>
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
      <fieldset [disabled]="true">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>SIgn in</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input required matInput type="email" placeholder="eg. test@email.com" formControlName="userEmailAddress">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input required matInput type="password" placeholder="eg. ************" formControlName="userPassword">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
      <mat-card-footer>
        <div class="text-center">Not Registered? <a routerLink="../register">Register</a></div>
      </mat-card-footer>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="inProgress" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

The result is

[image]

Still `<a>` tag is in enabled condition.

Is it possible to do like Google?

Comment: https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/angular-disable-a-form-while-preserving-state-of-controls-4212d8faad0e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable the entire form at once (Angular reactive form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854017/disable-the-entire-form-at-once-angular-reactive-form)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854017/disable-the-entire-form-at-once-angular-reactive-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a logic for this. But I don't know is it the best method.

login.component.css

```
.wrapper-disable{
  z-index: -1 !important;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events:none;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
}
.wrapper-disable *{
  pointer-events:none;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
}
```

login.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="{'signin-wrapper':true, 'wrapper-disable' : wrapperDisable}">
  <mat-card >
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>SIgn in</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <!-- <mat-divider></mat-divider> -->
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input required matInput type="email" placeholder="eg. test@email.com" formControlName="userEmailAddress">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input required matInput type="password" placeholder="eg. ************" formControlName="userPassword">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
      <mat-card-footer>
        <div class="text-center">Not Registered? <a routerLink="../register">Register</a></div>
      </mat-card-footer>
    </form>
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="inProgress" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
onFormSubmit(): void {

    if (this.loginForm.valid) {

      this.wrapperDisable = true;
      // 
}
```

output is:

[image]

It is working as expected!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[disabled]=true` on the `<form></form>` element?

Comment: Failed to compile. Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Comment: https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110